# Why is my bcp query not working?

Tags: c#, bcp

I'm beginner in C#, I want use the `bcp` utility in C# and to do so, I wrote this code:

```
 string connstr = "Data Source=192.168.50.172;Initial Catalog=CDRDB;User ID=CDRLOGIN;Password=beh1368421"; 

 //string connstr = "Enter your connection string here";
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "bcp";
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"select * from CDRTABLE"" queryout c:\filename.csv -S 192.168.50.172 -U CDRLOGIN -P beh1368421 -f -w";
 proc.Start();
```

That code runs, but `filename.csv` is not created on my `C:\` drive. What happened? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is [this "BCP" thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCP)?

Comment: Needs a leading ".  Print your string and try it manually from the console.

Comment: @UweKeim BCP use the in sql server for read from other sql server database and write query result in csv file

Comment: bcp: The bcp utility bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and a data file in a user-specified format. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: Does that bcp command work *outside* you program (eg. from the command line). If not: fix the command line and then look at integrating. If it does then there is a problem with your process launching code (start checking defaulted working directories);

Comment: How many times are you going to ask BCP questions without following up when people answer your question??? I remember at least two from the recent future that you simply abandoned. Did the answers help you? Did they not help you? How about at least dropping a comment when people **do** answer and show some respect for the effort they put in trying to help you.

Comment: @TT. i'm sorry for you ,say i'm beginner!

Answer (score 0):

For `Bcp` executing from `System.Diagnostics.Process()`, one should use the `-c` and `-CRAW` options.

Below is sample code.

```
string execPath = @"..\bcp.exe";
string localFile = @"MetaData.Table";
string localPath = @"..\OutputFolder";

System.Diagnostics.Process P = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
P.StartInfo.FileName = execPath;

P.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Concat("\"", "MetaData.Table", "\" out \"", localPath, "\\", localFile, ".dat\" -c -C RAW -t\"", separator, "\" -S \"", "(local)", "\" -T");

P.Start();
P.WaitForExit();
P.Close();
P.Dispose();
```

You can also use BCP in C# code using `BULK INSERT` Transact-SQL statement and using the `ExecuteNonQuery` method of `SqlCommand`.

Something like below will work:

```
sCommandText = "exec xp_cmdShell 'bcp.exe'"+Database + ".." + TableName + " in "  + 
                 FileName + " -c -q -U " + UserId + " -P " + Password +  "-t  ";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open(); 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = sCommandText;

return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```